# setting density upon image read with RMagick

Tags: ruby, vector, svg, imagemagick, rmagick

I am attempting to use RMagick to convert an SVG to a PNG of a different size.

When I read in the SVG with `Magick::Image.read('drawing.svg')` and write it out to drawing.png (the equivalent of just running `convert drawing.svg drawing.png` from the command line), the size is 744x1052.

Let's suppose I want the PNG to be twice as large as it is by default. You can't just read it in, resize it, then write it out, as that first rasterizes the SVG and then scales that image to be twice as large, losing quality and the entire benefit of using a vector graphic in the first place.  So instead, if I understand correctly, you're supposed to set the image's density upon read.

```
image = Magick::Image.read('drawing.svg'){self.density = 144}.first
```

But `image.density` still reports the density as "72x72", and if I write out the image it has the same size as before, 744x1052. It doesn't seem to matter how I specify the density upon read. With 144, "144", 144.0, "144.0", "144x144", and "144.0x144.0", it always comes back "72x72".

Running `convert -density 144 drawing.svg drawing.png` from the command line works as expected and generates a PNG that's twice as large as before, 2104x1488.

I'm using OS X 10.6.7, ImageMagick 6.7.0-0 (installed via MacPorts), RMagick 2.13.1, and Ruby 1.9.2p180. When I put my code into the context of a little Sinatra webapp on Heroku, it has the same incorrect behavior, so the issue does not seem to lie with OS X or MacPorts.

Answer (score 4):

Density is about resolution (i.e. dots per inch), not the rendered size. From the [fine manual](https://rmagick.github.io/imageattrs.html#density):

> The vertical and horizontal resolution in pixels of the image. The default is "72x72".

I think you're looking for [`resize`](https://rmagick.github.io/image3.html#resize) or [`resize!`](https://rmagick.github.io/image3.html#resize_bang):

> Changes the size of the receiver to the specified dimensions.
>
> You can specify the new size in two ways. Either specify the new width and height explicitly, or specify a scale factor, a number that represents the percentage change.

So this will work:

```
Magick::Image.read('drawing.svg').first.resize(2).write('drawing.png')
```

Or this:

```
img = Magick::Image.read('drawing.svg').first
img.resize!(2)
img.write('drawing.png')
```

I don't know why `convert` behaves differently than the library, there could be other default settings in play that have different defaults in the library or maybe `-density` does more than set the density.

If `resize` isn't doing the trick for you (and, based on your comments, it is happening too late to be of use), you can try setting the [`size` parameter](https://rmagick.github.io/info.html#size) in the block:

```
img = Magick::Image.read('drawing.svg'){ |opts| opts.size = '2104x1488' }.first
```

Of course, you have to know how big the SVG is before hand. You're supposed to be able to specify things like `200%x200%` for the geometry but `read` always ignores the flag on the [`Magick::Geometry`](https://rmagick.github.io/struct.html#Geometry) when I try it.

Comment: If I were just working with a raster to raster conversion, resize would definitely be what I wanted.  But if I resize after the SVG has been read, I'm upscaling a raster image, and so I get the [nasty antialiasing artifacts](http://i.imgur.com/vINJF.png) you would expect. The `convert` command seems to rasterize the SVG as a larger image in the first place, which produces [properly smooth lines](http://i.imgur.com/640WE.png).

Comment: It wouldn't let me edit my comment, but I wanted to mention [a thread I found in the ImageMagick forums](http://goo.gl/hVPt6) that says that one of the uses for `-density` is to specify the reading density for a vector image. It just apparently doesn't have the same meaning to RMagick as to `convert`.

Comment: @hynkle: Have a look at my update. You're supposed to be able to specify percentage geometries for `opts.size` but I can't get it to work or produce an error message telling me why it won't work. This is pretty typical for my interactions with ImageMagick though: great library if you can make it work, horrible interface.

Comment: @muistooshort this not seems to work anymore. I have tried it but chaning opts.size dont affects anything.